# Setting all radio buttons with name

Tags: javascript

I want to select all radio buttons with a specific name. Currently, i do this:

```js
var points = 0, size = 4;

function checkAnswer(answer, q) {
    if (answer) //If answer's right.
    {
      points += 10;
    } else //If answer's wrong.
    {
      points -= 10;
    }
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "You have " + points + " points."; //Display score
    while (size--) document.getElementsByClassName("test" + q)[size].disabled = "true";
    size = 4;
  }
```

```html
<h3>Question 1</h3>
<input class="test0" type="radio" name="q1" onClick="checkAnswer(0,0)">Answer
<br>
<input class="test0" type="radio" name="q1" onClick="checkAnswer(0,0)">Answer
<br>
<input class="test0" type="radio" name="q1" onClick="checkAnswer(1,0)">Right Answer
<br>
<input class="test0" type="radio" name="q1" onClick="checkAnswer(0,0)">Answer
<br>
<h3>Question 2</h3>
<input class="test1" type="radio" name="q2" onClick="checkAnswer(0,1)">Answer
<br>
<input class="test1" type="radio" name="q2" onClick="checkAnswer(1,1)">Right Answer
<br>
<input class="test1" type="radio" name="q2" onClick="checkAnswer(0,1)">Answer
<br>
<input class="test1" type="radio" name="q2" onClick="checkAnswer(0,1)">Answer
<br>

<p id="score">No score yet!</p>
```

I want to have a better way to do that, for example some way of getElementsByName, but not using that function (since it's mostly not supported). I suppose i could do that using attributes, but i dont know how to do that. Please help me, thanks.
Also, i prefer not to use jQuery.

Comment: Your `checkAnswer()` function is missing a closing `}`.  I think that's why your code may have "stopped working".  At least, that's what I'm seeing whenever I copy your snippet.

Comment: @zero298 You're right. Gonna fix that :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a `querySelectorAll()` and provide the correct CSS selector by keying off of the name attribute.  The `getRadsByName()` function will find all `<input>` tags that have their `name` attribute set to the value provided to the function.  You can tailor the query to your needs.

```js
// Wait for domready
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(docE) {

  // Name of our inputs
  var answerRadioNames = ["first", "second"];

  // Function to find all inputs with a certain name
  function getRadsByName(name) {
    var qs = "input[name='" + name + "']";
    var rad = document.querySelectorAll(qs);
    return rad;
  }

  // Function to have all found inputs initialize thier handles
  function radNameInitializer(name) {
    [].forEach.call(getRadsByName(name), radInitializer);
  }

  // Function to attach click handlers to inputs
  function radInitializer(currRad) {
    currRad.addEventListener("click", radClickHandler);
  }

  // Click hanlder which calls the disabler
  function radClickHandler(e) {
    [].forEach.call(getRadsByName(e.target.name), disabler);
  }

  // Function which disables the clicked radio
  function disabler(radToDisable) {
    radToDisable.disabled = true;
  }

  // Attach to all the names
  answerRadioNames.forEach(radNameInitializer);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="first" value="1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="first" value="2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="first" value="3" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="second" value="3" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="second" value="4" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="second" value="5" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Any simpler way? If possible no eventHandlers. The only thing i have problems with is how do i set all the **inputs named "q1"** to disabled = true. I'm satisfied with how the onClick work.    
So the only thing i need is an array automatically filled with the inputs, that i will set using that loop.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found an answer. Well, the thing i was really searching for is an equivalent for `getElementsByName()`
And i found one through a little coding. I think it's a good result and it suits me. Anyone could comment additions / corrections / improvements?

```js
function GimmeElementsByName(name)
{
  var FinalOutput = [], x = document.getElementsByTagName('input').length, i = 0; //For use later.
  while(x--)
  {
  if (document.getElementsByTagName('input')[x].name == name) //Apply to all inputs that's name is qSomething.
   {
    FinalOutput[i] = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[x]; //Array with all the matching inputs.
    i++;
   }
  }
  return FinalOutput;
}

//For example use
function Hello()
{
  var size = 4;
  while (size--) GimmeElementsByName('q1')[size].disabled = "true";
}
```

```html
This is an example use:  

<input type="button" value="Click here" onClick="Hello();">
<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1">
<input type="radio" name="q1">
<input type="radio" name="q1">
<input type="radio" name="q1">
<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2">
<input type="radio" name="q2">
<input type="radio" name="q2">
<input type="radio" name="q2">
```

Comment: Please cache the results of traversing the DOM in a variable, instead of traversing again and again at each step of the loop. And consider `querySelectorAll`.